# Exclude Values with Regex - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What would I use in standard SQL if I wanted to exclude regex matches in a field from being aggregated. The code runs; however it is **counting the values I have in the regex and I want it to exclude instead**. I have this code:

```
SELECT
    channelGrouping, 
    date,
    SUM(totals.timeOnSite) AS Session_Duration,
    SUM(totals.visits) AS Visits,
    AVG(totals.timeonSite/totals.visits) AS Avg_Time_per_Session,
    SUM(totals.bounces) AS Bounce,
    (SUM(totals.bounces)/SUM(totals.visits)) AS Bounce_rate
FROM
    `93868086.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY))
AND
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY 
    date,
    channelGrouping,
    geoNetwork.networkLocation 
HAVING
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(geoNetwork.networkLocation,
    r"^(ovh \(nwk\)|hostwinds llc.|bhost inc|prisma networks llc|psychz networks|buyvm services|private customer|secure dragon llc.|vmpanel|netaction telecom srl-d|hostigation|frontlayer technologies inc.|digital energy technologies limited|owned-networks|rica web services|netaction telecom srl-d|hurricane electric inc.|private customer - host.howpick.com|ssdvirt|sway broadband|detect network|gorillaservers inc.|micfo llc.| netaction telecom srl|egihosting|zenlayer inc|intercom online inc.|gs1 argentine|ovh hosting inc.|vps cheap inc.|limeip networks|blackhost ltd.|amazon.com inc.)$")
ORDER BY
    date ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you really want (which is not 100% clear from question) you should either simply add NOT to your HAVING statement

```
HAVING NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS ...
```

or  move exclude logic up to `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT
    channelGrouping, 
    date,
    SUM(totals.timeOnSite) AS Session_Duration,
    SUM(totals.visits) AS Visits,
    AVG(totals.timeonSite/totals.visits) AS Avg_Time_per_Session,
    SUM(totals.bounces) AS Bounce,
    (SUM(totals.bounces)/SUM(totals.visits)) AS Bounce_rate
FROM
    `93868086.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY))
AND
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
AND NOT
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(geoNetwork.networkLocation,
    r"^(ovh \(nwk\)|hostwinds llc.|bhost inc|prisma networks llc|psychz networks|buyvm services|private customer|secure dragon llc.|vmpanel|netaction telecom srl-d|hostigation|frontlayer technologies inc.|digital energy technologies limited|owned-networks|rica web services|netaction telecom srl-d|hurricane electric inc.|private customer - host.howpick.com|ssdvirt|sway broadband|detect network|gorillaservers inc.|micfo llc.| netaction telecom srl|egihosting|zenlayer inc|intercom online inc.|gs1 argentine|ovh hosting inc.|vps cheap inc.|limeip networks|blackhost ltd.|amazon.com inc.)$")
GROUP BY 
    date,
    channelGrouping,
    geoNetwork.networkLocation 
ORDER BY
    date ASC
```

Also note: you are missing `networkLocation` from final SELECT statement. not deadly but would be more sense to have it there

Comment: Wow. Can't believe it was that simple. Migrating from Legacy SQL to Standard and I am quite rusty. Thank you for your help

Comment: 4 more minutes and I can do exactly that! If i wanted to add multiple HAVING NOT clauses would I just supply a comma and add the next criteria to the expression?